# How do I Mass update owner in Contact and Account?

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, data-loader, dml

In my ORG I have a 20K Accounts and 50K Contacts. 
I want to update Contact and Account owner where owner is "Jai" to "Mrugesh".

How to update all Contact and Account owner?

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard "Mass Transfer" feature of salesforce.

- Goto Setup
- In the quick search, search for "Mass Transfer Records". It will be reflected under Data Management
- Open it and click on Transfer Accounts

  Select Transfer From as "Jai"
  Select Transfer As "Mrugesh"

  Select criteria as where Owner First Name is Jai (Add your additional parameters)
  Click find accounts and Transfer them

It will automatically transfers all related contacts to Mrugesh (But only contacts which below to existing owner i.e. Jai)

Answer (score 1):

For that amount of contacts and accounts, use data loader (you can download it from Salesforce).

Steps:

1) find the user id for Jai and Mrugesh. You can do this by going to the "manage user" menu and click edit next to each. The URL Will have the id

2) extract all the account where ownerid is the is for Jai

3) in excel, replace the ownerid with the id for Mrugesh

4) update the records.

That should also automatically move the contacts. If it doesn't, repeat steps 2 through 4 for contacts instead of accounts